# Optimizing icon usage?

Tags: android, icons, png, jpeg, android-resources

I got a new requirement to present an image instead of an error text if there is no items to show and the image almost have `440 KB (PNG)` in size that given by my UI/UX designer. So I don't think it's fair to use it straightforward. As it's a transparent background image it's not possible to reduce the size by converting into `JPG` format. I got 4 resolutions of the image for placing it in different resolution resource folder. but if I keep all of them in my APK, that itself take near 1 MB, So I had taken only one image from `drawable-xhdpi` folder and kept in `drawable-nodpi`.  Okay, So my queries as follows

1)  How can I efficiently use that image ?

2) Any worries if I use `JPG` icons as substitute of `PNG` ?

3) What about keeping images like these only in `drawable-nodpi` and setting size in different dimension file ?

Answer (score 0):

1) Convert the PNG to WebP if you only need to support API level 13+, otherwise use ZopfliPNG to optimize your PNG.

2) JPG does not support alpha channel and it's lossy.

3) Just put it in `drawable-xhdpi` and let Android scale the image for you. Only put images in `drawable-nodpi` if you don't want the image to be scaled.